# Superclass method being called even though object is of subclass

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, overriding

I was playing around with simple overloading overriding rules and found something interesting. Here is my code.

```
package com.demo;

public class Animal {

    private void eat() {
        System.out.println("animal eating");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Animal a = new Horse();
        a.eat();
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Horse eating");
    }
}
```

This program outputs the below.

> animal eating

Here is what I know:

- As we have `private void eat()` method, it is not definitely going to be accessed in a subclass, so the question of method overriding does not arise here as [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e11238) defines it clearly.
- Now that this is not method overriding, it is definitely not going to call `public void eat()` method from the Horse class
- Now our declaration `Animal a = new Horse();` is valid because of polymorphism.

Why is `a.eat()` invoking a method from the `Animal` class? We are creating a `Horse` object, so why does the Animal class' method get called?

Comment: Well, didn't you explain it just above. `a`'s declared type is Animal, not Horse, and Animal.eat() is private, so it can't be overridden, so it can't be called polymorphically. The subclass method would be called if it overrode the base method class, but it doesn't, so...

Comment: @JBNizet, yes but they why Animal class eat method is called that I am not able to understand. Is it because we have reference of type Animal class? But we have object of type Horse class. then why is it calling Animal class method?

Comment: All the compiler knows about `a` is that it's an Animal: that's its declared type. So the compiler looks for an eat() method in Animal. It finds one, and it's private, so it calls this method. And since it can't possibly be overridden, Animal.eat() is being called.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot, I got my confusion cleared now :)

Comment: If you *think* you're overriding a method in a subclass, add the `@Override` annotation: compilation will then fail if you aren't.

Comment: @AndyTurner, no I wasn't thinking I am overriding method :) I know it is not happening, I was just wondering why Animal class method gets called even though there is no Animal object. Reading from the answers, I  came to know it is due to method binding.

Comment: @Prasad then what is the question: if you know you aren't overriding the method, then it seems rather obvious that the superclass method is called, as it isn't overridden.

Comment: because I was not creating object of superclass Animal, and actual object was of Horse, which will not have access to private eat method from Animal. As there was no object of Animal class, still Animal class method was being called, that is what I was not able to understand.

Comment: I would love to know the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your confusion. Based on what you know:

You are right, `Horse.eat()` is not overriding `Animal.eat()` (as it is private).  In another word, when you call `anAnimal.eat()`, no late-binding happens and hence, you are simply calling `Animal.eat()`, which is what you see.

---

From your other comment, seems that your confusion is how the compiler is deciding what to call.  Here is a very high-level explanation:

When compiler sees  `Animal a =...; a.eat();`, it will try to resolve what to call.

For example, if it sees `eat()` is a static method, given `a` is a reference to `Animal`, compiler will translate it to call `Animal.eat()`.

If it is an instance method, and it encounters a method that may have been overridden by a child class, what the compiler does is, it will not generate instructions to call a specific method.  Instead, it will generate instructions to do some kind of lookup from a vtable.  Conceptually, each object will have a little table, which the key is the method signature, and the value is the reference to the actual method to call.  For example, if in your case, `Animal.eat()` is not private, what Horse's vtable will contain is something like `["eat()" -> "Horse.eat()"]`.  So at **runtime**, given an `Animal` reference and `eat()` is called, what happen is actually: lookup from the vtable of the referred object with `eat()`, and call the method associated.  (If the ref is pointing at a `Horse`, the method associated will be `Horse.eat()` ).  This is how the magic of late binding is done in most cases.

With an instance method that is not possible to be overridden, compilers do similar things as static methods and generate instructions to call that method directly.

(The above is not technically accurate, just a conceptual illustration for you to understand what happened)

Comment: thats very good explanation :) thanks a lot. Today is a good day, got somethign to learn

Comment: correct me If am wrong, basically `method` gets pass flag from compiler(compile time) and since there is no runtime error so everything(**access modifiers**) is ignored at runtime and therefore simple method invocation occurs?? and `eat()` is private in `Animal` so execution starts form `Animal`?

Comment: @AsteriskNinja hm.... I don't think it is correct, especially "execution starts from `Animal`" does not make sense to me

Comment: @AsteriskNinja The access methods are not being ignored -- `Animal.eat()` is indeed `private` -- but you are calling it _from within the `Animal` class_ and are therefore allowed to (if you moved your `main()` into separate class, you would get a compiler error).

Answer (score 24):

Methods marked `private` can't be overridden in subclasses because they're not visible to the subclass. In a sense, your `Horse` class has no idea whatsoever that `Animal` has an `eat` method, since it's marked `private`. As a result, Java doesn't consider the `Horse`'s `eat` method to be an override. This is primarily designed as a safety feature. If a class has a method it's marked `private`, the assumption is that that method is supposed to be used for the class internals only and that it's totally inaccessible to the outside world. If a subclass can override a `private` method, then it could potentially change the behavior of a superclass in an unexpected way, which is (1) not expected and (2) a potential security risk.

Because Java assumes that a `private` method of a class won't be overridden, whenever you call a `private` method through a reference of some type, Java will always use the type of the *reference* to determine which method to call, rather than using the type of the *object pointed at by that reference* to determine the method to call. Here, the reference is of type `Animal`, so that's the method that gets called, even though that reference points at a `Horse`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I understood that private methods are not overridden and that I've mentioned in question itself. Horse method will not get called because it is not overriding.  My only question is why Animal class method is being called even though it is Horse class object.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I guess you may want to take a look to see how late-binding for method is achieved (by v-table).  A high level understand should be enough for you to understand the behavior

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I think I see what you're confused about. I've updated my answer accordingly - let me know if you still have any questions!

Comment: @AdrianShum, I will surely look into it

Comment: @templatetypedef yes that is exactly my doubt :) So private methods are called in reference variable type as conclusion in this scenario :)

Comment: The explanation as to why private methods can't be overwritten is very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

The thing that you are probably overlooking here: your main method is within the Animal class. Therefore it is no problem to call the private method eat() from the same class. If you move your main method into another class, you will find that calling eat() on an **Animal** will then lead to a compiler error!

And of course: if you had put the @Override annotation on eat() within Horse, you would have received a compiler error, too. Because, as other have nicely explained: you are not overriding anything in your example.

So, in essence:

1. You were not overriding anything
2. You were not calling the method you thought you were calling

Finally, regarding your comment: of course there is an **Animal** object. Horse is **extending** Animal; so any Horse-object is also an Animal object. That is why you were able to write down

```
Animal a = new Horse();
```

But the important thing to understand: after that line, the compiler doesn't know any more that "a" is **actually** a Horse. You declared "a" as Animal; and therefore the compiler allows you to call methods that Animal declares. Keep in mind: **inheritance** is basically about describing an "IS-A" relationship: in your example, a Horse IS A Animal.

Comment: Yes thats true and I understood it. My only confusion is that even though there is no object of Animal, Animal class eat method is getting called. This is my doubt. Is it calling Animal class method only because we have reference variable of type Animal?

Answer (score 3):

In short, you are overloading the intended meaning of "overriding" in Java :-).

Let's pretend that someone else wrote the `Animal` class: (rewriting it slightly, without changing any semantics, but to demonstrate a good practice). We will also assume that `Animal` compiles and runs fine:

```
public class Animal {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Animal a = new Animal(); // yes, Animal, no Horse yet.
        a.eat();
    }
    ///// Animal's private methods, you should not look here
    private void eat() {
        System.out.println("animal eating");
    }
    ///// Animal's private methods, you should not look here
}
```

This is a good Java coding practice because the author of `Animal` class doesn't want you, the reader of that code, to really know anything about `Animal`'s private business.

Next, you look at the `public static void main` method of `Animal` and correctly infer that there is a method named `eat()` defined there. At this point, following holds:

1. Like any other class in Java, `Animal` extends `Object`.
2. You look at the public (and protected) methods of `Object` and find that there is no such method as `eat()`. Given that `Animal` compiles fine, you can infer that `eat`ing must be `Animal`'s private business! There's no other way that `Animal` could compile. Thus, without looking at `Animal`'s private business, you could infer that there is an `eat()` method in `Animal` class that is *private*!

Now let's say that your intent was to create another animal named `Horse` as a specialized `Animal` and give it a special behavior of eating. You figure that you are *not* going to look into Java Lang Spec and find out all the rules of doing so and just use the `extends` keyword and be done with it. The first version of `Horse` then emerges. You have heard somewhere however that it is better to clarify your intent of *overriding* (this is one thing you are now certain -- you do want to *override* `eat`ing behavior of `Horse`):

```
class Horse extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Horse eating");
    }
}
```

Right; you add the tag `@Override`. This is always a good idea, admittedly, at an increased verbiage (It is a good practice for a few reasons that we'll not go into here).

You try to compile `Horse.java` and you see:

```
Error:(21, 5) java: method does not override or implement a 
method from a supertype
```

Thus, the compiler that knows the Java programming language better than us, tells us that we are, in fact, *not* overriding or *implementing* a method that is declared in a *supertype*.

Now the handling of overriding in Java becomes clearer to us. Since we are supposed to only override that behavior that is designed for overriding, namely the public and protected methods, we should be careful about how the superclasses are written. In this case, inadvertently, the superclass `Animal`, which was apparently designed for extension, made it impossible for the subclasses to override the `eat`ing behavior!

Even if we removed the `@Override` tag to get rid of the technicality of the compiler error/warning, we wouldn't necessarily be doing the right thing because at runtime, as you observed, the unintended method whose signature matches, gets called. That is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Private Methods Cannot Be Overridden.

http://ideone.com/kvyngL

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Animal {

    private void eat() {
        System.out.println("animal eating");
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Horse eating");
    }
}
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
                Animal a = new Horse();
        a.eat();

    }
}
```

Comment: The code here seems pretty similar to the code in the question. Is there something different about it?

Comment: No I wanted to show the error that the java compiler returns, telling that the private eat method cannot be overriden.

Comment: @templatetypedef `main()` is in other class

Comment: The error reported at ideone is about the call to `a.eat()` not being able to invoke the private method `eat`, not about trying to override a `private` method.

Comment: basically he is trying to show that one cannot override private methods, I guess

Comment: Correct Asterisk Ninja

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
Animal a = new Horse();
```

In this situation **a** points to **Horse** object as if it is an object of **Animal** type.

`a.eat()` is private in **Animal** class, so it cannot be overridden, and that's why `a.eat()` comes from **Animal**